# Pip3 Install --upgrade pip==version Not working

Tags: pip, python-3.8

I'm on version 20.0.4 according to pip3 --version.

When I run pip3 install --upgrade pip==20.2.4 it appears to install successfully.

When I type pip3 --version again it still says 20.0.4 and even says the 20.0.4 in pip3 list.

I notice if I type pip --version it is on 20.2.4. So apparently I'm updating pip but not pip3. How do I get it to target the right pip version?

What gives?

Comment: Are you installing from an elevated command prompt? Also, what is your OS (I'm currently assuming it's Windows)?

Comment: Bro , have you use this command ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip```

Comment: @micpap25 ubuntu 20.04 forgot to mention that. It's not failing to install though it's just installing for the wrong instance of pip.

Comment: @co_ssm tried that but python3 and it didn't seem to do anything different.

Comment: issue still exists. not working for me.